# How can I use multiple GPUs when batchsize=1?

Tags: deep-learning, caffe

I am trying to training deep CNN models for semantic segmentation. Because the model size and the resolution of the input image are large, it runs out of memory even with batchsize=1. How can I use multiple GPUs to get more available memories under this circumstance? (Currently I am using caffe)
Thanks.

Comment: It seems that you'd better use other frameworks e.g. mxnet, tensorflow, to get model parallelism.(caffe only supports data parallelism for multiple GPUs)

Comment: Thanks@Dale, I think I should start learning TensorFlow.

Answer (score 0):

**Dale** already gave you the basic answer: Caffe doesn't support model parallelism.

Do you have the option of reducing the input size?  Does it make sense to shrink the image (losing resolution) or to break the image into pieces (losing full-image cohesion)?  Would that make the input and model fit?  If you already have your model coded and debugged in Caffe, it would be nice to at least smoke-test the topology on the current system.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Is it possible to realize modle parallelism between GPU and CPU? That is, puting the latter layers on the CPU? （set the gpu code as unimplemented）

Comment: I'm not sure; I work in a purely CPU environment.  The mixed environments I know of are CPU-mastered GPU systems, where the CPU doesn't fully participate in the training computations.  Please note that this is possibly a different question; Caffe won't support it.

Comment: @Prune: pieces means randomly crop the image into patches. Is it right? Do you have any reference to prove that break the image into patches tend to losing full-image cohesion? Which is good cropping option between H/8xW/8 and another is H/2xW/2 from original HxW? Thanks

Comment: "good" depends on the data: you have to experiment to see which works best for you.  Again, you need to test the changes to see what works well for you.